# Select rows in MySQL table with specific or default value

Tags: mysql, select

I am new here so sorry if it i a silly question. I need help with a mysql query.

We offer various services to our client. Our services and prices are in a table like this

```
service    | customer    | price
  1        |     0       | 1.1 
  2        |     0       | 2.1 
  3        |     0       | 1.3
  2        |     1       | 1.9 
  3        |     2       | 1.2
```

If customer = 0, then it is default price. If customer > 0, then it is customer specific price for that service.

We need to show prices for all the services to individual customers. Hence, we need to query such that if customer specific price is present, we show that else default price.

So for customer 1, it should show

```
service    | customer    | price
  1        |     0       | 1.1 
  2        |     1       | 1.9 
  3        |     0       | 1.3
```

For customer 2, it should show

```
service    | customer    | price
  1        |     0       | 1.1 
  2        |     0       | 2.1 
  3        |     2       | 1.2
```

For any other customers,

```
service    | customer    | price
  1        |     0       | 1.1 
  2        |     0       | 2.1 
  3        |     0       | 1.3
```

I have attempted

```
select service, customer, price from services where (customer=1 or customer = 0) order by customer desc
```

but it does not produce required output

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results you want by doing a self `JOIN` of the prices for customer 0 with the values for customer 1 (or whichever customer you want), using a `LEFT JOIN` on `service` and replacing any `NULL` values with the price for customer 0:

```
SELECT s0.service,
       COALESCE(s.price, s0.price) AS price
FROM (SELECT service, price
      FROM services
      WHERE customer = 0) s0
LEFT JOIN services s ON s.service = s0.service AND s.customer = 1
ORDER BY service
```

Output (for `customer = 1`):

```
service     price
1           1.10
2           1.90
3           1.30
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f141cfc86f493e5f0e55e08f9bea8bf8) (also shows results for `customer = 2` and `customer = 3`)